# How do I fix error TS1015: Parameter cannot have question mark and initializer?

Tags: typescript

I have just upgraded to TypeScript beta 0.9 and now I'm getting the error:

> TS1015: Parameter cannot have question mark and initializer

This was valid before, how do I fix this?

Here's an example of the code that's generating this error:

```
functionName(parameterName?: typeName = defaultValue): typeName
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

If you look in the [TypeScript Language Specification](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md) document you can find a wealth of detail about the language syntax.

Section [3.9.2](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#392-call-signatures) describes call signatures i.e. the syntax used to call functions and constructors etc.

Section [3.9.2.2](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#3922-parameter-list) is specifically about the parameters associated with a call.

It defines optional parameters as:

> *AccessibilityModifieropt BindingIdentifierOrPattern ? TypeAnnotationopt*
>
> *AccessibilityModifieropt BindingIdentifierOrPattern TypeAnnotationopt Initializer*

We can see see that either using '?' **OR** providing a default value *Initializer* will mark the parameter as being optional.

So to fix the compiler error you can simply remove the '?' and leave the default value and it will remain as an optional parameter as you intend.

Comment: Updated link to the spec: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md

Comment: @DomHede Thanks! I've updated to point at the latest version, and to use the latest info.

Comment: both links are dead

Comment: I think this may be the official documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/